# Create a body impression on a foam cube mattress

Tags: animation, physics, cloth-simulation

I've been trying to create a simple animation where there is a body imprint on a foam layer made of cubes. I'm using cloth physics on the mattress, and moving it up to the body mesh to create the impression. However, the impression on the mesh looks very crumpled and I need it to be smooth. I'm fairly new to blender but have 3D experience in Maya. Animating and using physics though are also pretty new to me. The only setting that is really changed from default I think is the Quality steps I increased to 10, and object collisions are on. This is the tutorial I started with: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PF9h2panbSA , I also watched several others on cloth and also soft bodies, but can't seem to get the effect I need.

I have a body mesh, the foam cube mesh and a camera in the scene. The ultimate goal is to render out an animation of the body impression forming on the foam layer. The body mesh does not render.

I believe I was able to upload the blend file here: [image]

Here is the wireframe, I added a subdivide modifier and also turned on self-collisions on the mesh. Not sure if both are necessary.

[image: Foam cube wire frame, crumpled when trying to make impression]

Comment: pls provide blend file because you didn't show us any setting you made. thx

Comment: I think a 'Solid' View showing the wireframe of your cubes would be a more informative illustration, if you could edit to show that..and, as @Chris says, the quickest route to sharing your settings would be a .blend on https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @RobinBetts I added a wireframe and the blender file as well - thanks

Comment: @Zerosiero thanks.